# Why is the adapter not working?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, adapter

I have two applications named `app` and `anotherapp` respectively along with one class library `myadp.dll`

`app` contains:

```
using myadp;
namespace app
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void bt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Class1 c = new Class1();
            tbinapp.Text = c.st;
        }
    }
}
```

`anotherapp` contains:

```
using myadp;
namespace anotherapp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void anotherbt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Class1 ad = new Class1();
            ad.st = anothertb.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

And `myadp.dll` contains:

```
namespace myadp
{
    public class Class1
    {
      public  string st = "this is from adapter ";
    }
}
```

I am trying to pass a value from `anotherapp` to `app` using `myadp` as an adapter. But it is not working. I am assuming that it is not working because each application is creating a new instance of the class `Class1` in `myadp`. Am I right? How do test this and fix it?

Comment: You're looking for *Inter process communication*

Comment: yes , you are absolutely right ! ,but in mys case inter app communication as well !

Comment: What do you mean by *inter app communication*? and how that differs from *Inter process communication* ? You can't share memory between processes just like that. You need to use any of the [IPC mechanisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)

Comment: yes its almost the same thing ...

Comment: Shared DLL is not a bridge for communication between 2 processes, it is just the _reused code_ that you don't need to copy and paste to each project. And you are correct that `each application is creating a new instance of the class Class1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally it worked (here the adapter's `readfromnotepad()` is returning string that was on the edit fielt in the notepad )

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

using System.Threading.Tasks;
//using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;

namespace finally_adapter
{
    public class adapt_
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr GetWindow(IntPtr hWnd, GetWindow_Cmd uCmd);
        enum GetWindow_Cmd : uint {
   GW_HWNDFIRST = 0,
   GW_HWNDLAST = 1,
   GW_HWNDNEXT = 2,
   GW_HWNDPREV = 3,
   GW_OWNER = 4,
   GW_CHILD = 5,
   GW_ENABLEDPOPUP = 6
}

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);


        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, [Out] StringBuilder lParam);

        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern Int32 FindWindow(String lpClassName, String lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);




        int len;
        public string strin;
        const int WM_GETTEXT = 0x000D;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(100);
        IntPtr hwnd;
        public adapt_()
        {

        }
        public string readfromnotepad()
        {
            string lpclassname = "Edit";
            string lpwindowname = "Notepad";
            int temp = FindWindow(lpwindowname,null);
            hwnd = (IntPtr)temp;
            StringBuilder temps = new StringBuilder(100);
            IntPtr edit_hwnd = GetWindow(hwnd, GetWindow_Cmd.GW_CHILD);
            IntPtr msg_hwnd = SendMessage(edit_hwnd, WM_GETTEXT, (IntPtr)100, temps);

            return temps.ToString();


        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Wow. Do you even understand what you are doing here? Do u use this class just to communicate btw. two other classes. Or did i get u wrong.

Comment: HEll YEA !............this is just to check whether the concept is correct  or not !

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that each app is creating a new instance of `Class1`, however it is deeper than that. You seem to be misunderstanding a basic part of how classes work in code

Two apps which share the namespace `myadp` can both create the class `Class1` in that namespace, however the *instances* of those classes are not shared between them.

Think of it as two kids who each have a set of instructions for building a lego house. Using the blocks they have, they can both build the same *kind* of house, but they're not the *same* house. If kid A builds a house, kid B does not have that house to play with, he has to build his own.

To fix your problem, you need somewhere to store the data, like a database, or a public method in one app which can be accessed by another.